# Strange empty white space above toolbar

Tags: java, android, xml

hy,
i working on an android app i have problem with my main activity i have strange empty white space above toolbar. in my app i have one activity that does not have empty space above toolbar i tried to copy some of the layout in this activity but nothing works maybe i have to add something else
this is my layout for main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#4F5EB1"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/griview"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:title="@string/app_name"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white" />

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/griview"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="670dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:columnWidth="100dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/main_activity_toolbar" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

can someone please help me with this issue

thank you so much for your help